# why google analytics include my click after I installed it by google tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have installed google analytics by google tag manager, but every time I enter my website and click something, google analytics include my click. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this is better posted on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to track page views, make sure on Google Analytics tag inside your GTM you have firing rule set to only "All Pageviews".

Based on the event that you have mentioned, it looks like you have an additional firing rule available that is set to fire on "all clicks". You can check the GA tag if it has multiple firing rules, if yes.. you can only keep the pageviews one and remove the other.

Comment: Inside my Google Analytics tag, I have only "All Pageviews" and I don't have any additional firing rule.

You mean that you have not faced the same problem?

To solve this problem, I followed the instruction on the link below and I was successful at excluding my traffic in Google Analytics.

https://www.rubenvezzoli.online/exclude-internal-traffic-google-analytics-using-google-tag-manager/

Comment: These two things are entirely different, the problem that you have mentioned on question is that when you enter the site and click anyone it register include the click. Maybe you are not explaining the issue correctly. Do you want to exclude your own visits ?

Comment: I want to exclude my own visits. Before, I installed google analytics by Wordpress plugin and I did not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is gtm.click then it should be just fine . I attached a screen shot here . If you see the something like this when you click any where on the page then it is fine . Gtm automaticlly trigger this event when you implement any onclick trigger

[image: gtm.click]

Comment: When I open my website, Google Analytics tag fire and I don't see something like this.

Comment: you will see something like only if you click on your page

Answer (score -1):

Inside my Google Analytics tag, I have only "All Pageviews" and I don't have any additional firing rule.

You mean that you have not faced the same problem?

To solve this problem, I followed the instruction on the link below and I was successful at excluding my traffic in Google Analytics.

https://www.rubenvezzoli.online/exclude-internal-traffic-google-analytics-using-google-tag-manager/